# Javascript: get all elements by class name on page load NOT WORKING

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a script that would transform existing elements on page to new ones when the page loads, but fail, obviously.

Here's a really weird output of an array of those elements (states three elements are there, but shows only one):

[image]

```html
<html>
<head>
<script>
var f__inputs = [];

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  f__init();
}, false);

function f__init(){
 f__inputs = document.body.getElementsByClassName("superinput");
 console.log(f__inputs);
 f__insert();
}

function f__insert(){
 for(var i=0;i<f__inputs.length;i++){
  f__inputs[i].id = "superinput-wrapper-" + i;
  f__inputs[i].className = "superinput-wrapper";
  var d = f__inputs[i].getAttribute("data-fields");
  for(var j=0;j<d;j++){
   var input = document.createElement("input");
   input.setAttribute("data-wrap",i);
   input.setAttribute("data-pos",j);
   input.setAttribute("size","1");
   input.setAttribute("type","text");
   input.id = "superinput-input-" + j;
   input.className = "superinput-input";
   
   if(j!=0){
    input.setAttribute("disabled","true");
    input.disabled = true;
   }
   f__inputs[i].appendChild(input);
  }
 }
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>
 <b>Task 90.</b>
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
 <div class="superinput" data-fields="6"></div>
</p>
<p>
 <b>Task 91.</b>
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
 <div class="superinput" data-fields="6"></div>
</p>
<p>
 <b>Task 91.</b>
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
 <div class="superinput" data-fields="6"></div>
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Any idea why is that happening?

Comment: Being pedantic but its not an array.

Comment: i've found situations where the result of console.log is not reliable if the logged object is changed between the time it's logged and the time you examine it in the developer tools.  it would be more helpful to see the generated html.  btw, instead of waiting for us to provide an answer, consider stepping thru your code with the debugger and see how the DOM is modified at each step.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName()` will give you a NodeList, specifically a HTMLCollection which is an array-*like* object. Some basic properties can be used on it like `.length` but not the Array methods and properties exclusive to Array (and to certain degree String), like `split`, `push`, `reduce`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things.

1. Mouse over the [i] and you'll see it tells you that the values of the array are "frozen" when you expand it and may not reflect the realtime values.
2. `getElementsByClassName` is a *live list*. This means when you set `className = "something-else"`, it is removed from the list. For this reason, it is recommended that you loop through them using `for( i=l-1; i>=0; i--)` instead of the usual loop.

Comment: a live list is probably what caused problems, didn't really knew those were a thing! thanks, problem solved.